# Windows 7 on an old motherboard (Gigabyte ga-8i915pl-g). Which SO to install?

Tags: windows, motherboard, bootable-media, cryptomining

So I have an old motherboard (Gigabyte ga-8i915pl-g) and wanted to know if I can install Windows 7 on it. I need it for mining purposes, and since NiceHash requires W7 at least in order to run.

Mobo page has drivers up to Windows Vista. So, does that mean I cant install W7?

I have a bootable usb with W10, but its not working, it says: "Invalid partition table". I looked around and found myself unable to run that W10 bootable usb. If I make a W7 usb could I install? Or Windows version isnt the problem here.

I also have a HDD with W10 on it and its unable to boot. It detects the HDD but its not booting Windows.

Extra: If so, is there any way I can get to mine with NiceHash with this motherboard?

CPU is Pentium-4 630.

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you probably could even run Windows 10. Depending on the specifics of the motherboard you might be unable to boot using USB and might have to have an actual CD-ROM to install. Check your BIOS settings and motherboard manual for information in regards to booting options and order.

Comment: I have a W10 HDD and its unable to boot. It detects the HDD but its not booting Windows. If I try to Boot via USB a W10 installer, it says: "Invalid partition table". I looked around and found myself unable to run that W10 bootable usb. If I make a W7 usb could I install? Or Windows version isnt the problem here.

Comment: I need more information.1, Processor ? 2, Hard disk Drive size ?

Comment: @vembutech CPU is Pentium-4 630. Hard Disk is a WD Green 1TB.

Comment: Moving an HDD from one system to another with an already installed Windows 10 does have various caveats like using GPT and Secure Boot neither of which might be supported by your particular board. If it did show you invalid partition table you were able to boot some kind of OS/installer?

Comment: if you really want to keep it running try to Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: @Seth HDD shows up but I get stuck on "Searchin PCI devices screen". It's when booting a W10 instaler usb when I get the "Invalid partition table" message. Not able to boot nothing yet. I still havnt tried with a W7 one.

Comment: @vembutech I already tried a W10 32bit usb. Same partition message. Ill try a W7 32bits SO. Although CPU specs tells it can handle 64bit.

Comment: @Flowen You can try to Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: Okay Ill try this in some hours since I have some W7 and W8.1 DVD's at home. Ill give feedback in order to mark answers as helpfull.

Comment: @Seth I tried with an old IDE CD-ROM reader and its booting. Windows 7 is being installed right now.

Answer (score 1):

The latest
[drivers for Gigabyte ga-8i915pl-g](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-8I915PL-G-rev-1x#support-dl)
are for Vista, which might maybe still be compatible with Windows 7,
although not too many drivers are to be found there.
Check also if you have the latest BIOS.

You may introduce the drivers during the installation of Windows 7
or via slipstream (google for it).

Comment: Sure I'll check if latest BIOS. Although I dont know what is this for.

Comment: Last version of BIOS is already installed. I fixed with a CD-ROM reader.